# Installation local perl and modules from bash

Tags: perl, cpan

My scripts require a new version of perl, which I have installed into a local directory, to avoid corrupting the packaged version of perl that comes with Debian.

I configured and installed a tarball of perl with:

```
Configure -des -Dprefix=/root/perl
make
make install
```

Then I called cpan with:

```
/root/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

Every time I install a module I do this:

```
$/root/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[2]> install Getopt::Long
cpan[2]> install WWW::Mechanize
cpan[2]> install File::Find::Rule
```

With a system version of perl I used to be able to do this from Bash:

```
$cpan -i DBI
```

How can I use a similiar command from bash, without needing to open up the cpan shell each time I need to install a module?

**Edit:** I should have read the documentation more thoroughly. 
The solution is:

```
/root/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install Getopt::Long'
```

Or (Thanks, suddenmoves)

`/root/perl/bin/cpan -i Getopt::Long`

Comment: Or You could just create an alias for quick access to the local cpan shell. Thanks, that's useful.

Comment: Also worth looking at perlbrew to install custom perls and cpanm as an installer: https://metacpan.org/module/GUGOD/App-perlbrew-0.62/bin/perlbrew https://metacpan.org/module/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.6909/bin/cpanm

Comment: +1 for Perlbrew. It takes care of all this for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a full install of perl under /root/perl, is there not a `/root/perl/bin/cpan` executable you can run?

Comment: That's better. `/root/perl/bin/cpan -i Getopt::Long`